# How to optimize log L with optim and comparing with OLS?

Tags: r

I would like to optimize a normal distribution with respect to b (with fixed variance  = 1):

But i have some troubles to finish it.

First I defined a vector of my (in)dependent variable:

```
   set.seed(1001)
   outcome<-rnorm(1000,sd = 1)
   covariate<-rnorm(1000,sd = 1)
```

Here I define  the log-likelihood

```
   loglike <- function(par, outcome, covariate){
               cov <- as.matrix(cbind(1, covariate))
               xb <- cov * par
              (- 1/2* sum((outcome - xb)^2))
   }
```

Now optimize:

```
                  opt.normal <- optim(par = 0.1,fn = loglike,outcome=outcome,cov=covariate, method = "BFGS",  control = list(fnscale = -1),hessian = TRUE)
```

However I get different results when running an simple OLS. However maximizing log-likelihhod and minimizing OLS should bring me to a similar estimate. I suppose there is something wrong with my optimization.

```
                  summary(lm(outcome~covariate))
```

Comment: instead of y=outcome, outcome=outcome, and then include cov=covariate directly after.  You need to pass in all the parameters to your function loglike in the optim call, as they are defined in loglike.   y is not an argument of optim or loglike

Comment: opt.normal <- optim(par = 0.1, fn = loglike, outcome = outcome,cov =covariate,method = "BFGS", control = list(fnscale = -1),hessian = TRUE) Error in cov %*% par : non-conformable arguments

Comment: par is a single value whose dim attribute is NULL, probably why it's non-conformable with cov, as R is looking to do matrix multiplication with %*%

Comment: woot woot no problem

Comment: the only thing I still not fully understand is the fact that a simple OLS summary(lm(outcome~covariate)) generates a different output that my par from optim(). I suppose there is still something wrong with the optim function

Comment: Should you expect them to be the same?  You're not using the same method for optimizing in each case

Comment: could also be because optim looks to optimize over all values of par.  By setting par to a single value, to me this means that you don't have any ability to optimize because optim looks at all values of par, but there's only 1, so return of the function for that value of par must be the optimum value, there aren't any other values of par over which to search